# problems with symfony2 images (403 forbidden)

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, assetic

I uploaded symfony2 project to servergrove.com and after this created assets using

```
php app/console assets:install --symlink web
```

and also

```
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

After these steps I can't access images in the `web/bundles` folder, I get a "403 forbidden" error.

The URL to my site is http://myserjtankian.com.preview-sg111.servergrove.com/

Comment: Your `img` tag's source pointing to folder on localhost `http://localhost/glendale/web/uploads/news/landscape_thumbnails/`, also check folders/files permissions

Comment: i know about these images, but if you open developer tool, you'll see other files in this domain, and server return not 404 error, but 403 forbidden, i set chmod 777

Comment: i think problem is that assets creates symlink, and apache can't go to symlinks?

Comment: Does your directory rule in apache conf has [`Options FollowSymLinks`](http://superuser.com/questions/244245/how-do-i-get-apache-to-follow-symlinks) ?

Answer (score 2):

You may fix that using this command line (without **--symlink web** arg) :

```
php app/console assets:install
```

This will install assets as hard copies.

Hope it's helpful

Best regard

Comment: Thanks, this was the winning answer for me.